# Can ActiveJob be used without ActiveRecord (ie, we use MongoID)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, resque, rails-activejob

Trying to do this but jobs fail when they are run with

```
Exception: NameError
Error: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord
```

I am using Rails 4.2, and have removed active record from the dependencies in application.rb like so:

```
#config/application.rb
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```